# How delete rows from dataframe after comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, comparison

I want to filter my dataframe, use the part of `filter` with condition. And I do't know how to do it

```
import numpy as np


table = pd.DataFrame({'movie': ['thg', 'thg', 'mol', 'mol', 'lob', 'lob'],
                  'rating': [3., 4., 5., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                  'name': ['John', 'Paul', 'Adam', 'Graham', 'Eva', 'Thomas']})

filter = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Paul','Adam', 'Graham', 'Eva', 'Thomas'],
                       'qty': [1, 1, 3, 10, 7, 5]})
```

```
>>> table 
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
1   thg    Paul       4
3   mol    Adam       5
4   mol  Graham     NaN
5   lob     Eva     NaN
6   lob  Thomas     NaN
```

I know that this doesn't work, but I can't change this, help me please

```
result=df[(df['name'] == filter[qty<3]) ]


>>> result 
  movie    name  rating
0   thg    John       3
1   thg    Paul       4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
table[table['name'].isin(filt.loc[filt['qty']<3,'name'])]
```

---

```
  movie  rating  name
0   thg     3.0  John
1   thg     4.0  Paul
```

Note: i have changed the `filter` variable to `filt` since `filter` is a builtin function and you should not name a variable with such name

Comment: Ah, you got this one!

Comment: *builtin function and you should not name a variable with such name* can not agree more ~

Answer (score 2):

You can try with. I am undeleting this answer because of not using `loc` unlike the other answers, although it is essentially the same:

```
result = table[table['name'].isin(filter[filter['qty']<3]['name'].values)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`callable`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-callable) :

```
table[table['name'].isin(df_filter.loc[lambda x: x['qty']<3, 'name'])]


  movie  rating  name
0   thg     3.0  John
1   thg     4.0  Paul
```

or [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
table.merge(df_filter.loc[lambda x: x['qty'].lt(3), ['name']])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a more concise solution, why not use query:

```
df=table.merge(filter,on="name")
df.query("qty<3")
```